# How to change image url dynamically using angularjs / javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs

Earlier,  I created a loading gif that turned into a checkmark. The idea is that I can use that specific gif for every single item on the **same** page. The problem is that my page seems to give the same picture the same url (as I append the date to the image via JS).

I wanted to use angularjs for this specific problem, but couldn't find anything. So at that point, I settled for trying JavaScript instead. Though knowing how to do this in both would be even better. Ideally, angularjs would be good, but knowing JS would be a great asset.

All I found for angular didn't help:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDate
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5BdateTimeLocal%5D
```

And then, for JS, every StackOverflow post I found had to do with changing the url of the image. HOWEVER, this seems to work only when reloading the page itself, including what I attempted with JS myself:

```
<script>
    var d = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("validation_gif").src = 
      "images/validation/validation_gif.gif?ver=" + 
       d.getTime();
</script>
```

I also tried with `Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999999999999) + 1);` first, but then with the date time just in case.

Comment: what does the `ver` parameter do? How does that load a different image other than `validation_gif.gif`?

Comment: @Ronnie I suppose you could ignore that. I was focusing on d.getTime(), not on a parameter...

Comment: I just dont understand what you are trying to do with time and how it relates to your image.

Comment: oh ,I think I get it. Are you thinking the image is cached or something and adding a param will load the image fresh?

Comment: @Ronnie. Yes, though I'm actually trying to get it to either re-load when someone types in a correct email address for example, OR to append a random number (or date stamp, assuming the date stamp has seconds in it). So when the green checkmark appears after typing the email, then I would need the animation of the gif to do that all over again after someone types in his name, his number etc.

Comment: Ok, makes a little more sense. So you want a checkmark to show up next to an input field when it is correct? Am I understanding that?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/heN9g/

Comment: @Ronnie. I can already do that. I'm referring to the image (being a gif) re-loading. I am talking about the mere animation of the loading image followed by the checkmark. As it now stands, if I input data in Field A, the animation occurs before showing the green checkmark (which is the last part of the gif). If I input data in Field B, the animation will not happen - since the image has been cached, it only shows you the end of the animation, which basically is a static checkmark.

Comment: why not just use two images? A loading gif and a checkmark?

Comment: @Ronnie I thought about using that to be honest, but at that point, I hadn't figured if it would have been clean. Did you have something like this in mind to start the code? Check out the code here: : http://www.devppl.com/forum/making-an-image-appear-and-then-disappear-vt18031.html

Comment: ok, what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/A2FH3/1/

Comment: @Ronnie. This is very strange. I tried your fiddle, and integrated it in work, but whenever I type in anything, it won't do anything UNTIL I type something after the @. It will load for a while (as expected) and then place a green checkmark. Of course, that is wrong in my plunker for two reasons: the loading UI "validation" should start when starting to write the email; furthermore, it shouldn't allow a green checkmark when the this is incomplete. I've been on it for hours now, but I can't see why it's wrong. You can verify this in my plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/lNYSTNY4b3MppxDvDzVM/preview

Comment: @Ronnie. I fixed the minor problem I had. I guess the keyboard got stuck on a letter - didn't realize it till today.  Anyhow, if you would like to add your answer as an answer, I'd be more than happy to up it and make it as the answer.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible. How would you have been able to type any of this lol

Comment: @Ronnie lol, copy/paste into DW. ctrl key apparently got stuck, it undid the last commented part (when I pressed z instead of x) -_- I only realized this this morning.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `ng-src` would solve your problem using angular.  Plain `src` is evaluated before angular gets to it.  [See the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

That said, I'm not sure why you would need to do this.  Could you explain more what the problem is?

Comment: That doesn't work. Imagine you are typing your name in a form. Great, you got your name right, then a green checkmark appears. But then, you got to type in your email, great, you wrote it correctly, so then a green checkmark appears. Ideally, as dumb as it sounds, I would prefer the loading of the gif to happen again. Why? Sure, use dif gifs! But, I have multiple sections with the same info. So, since I don't want the user to reload the page, the same email gif would load again. Since this is already cached, it loads only the checkmark, and not the animation.

Comment: @user54600 Why don't you instead animate the opacity from 0 to 1 whenever the checkmark appears?  You could also transition the size if you want to make it more obvious.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll have to discuss that possibility with them. Thanks for that CSS tip, hadn't even considered that.

Comment: @user54600 Sure thing. One other option you might want to look into is using an icon font like [icoMoon](http://icomoon.io/) (there are others out there, but that's the one I use). Your checkmark would be a scalable vector and you could set the color to whatever you like. It's also easy to change the icon from one to another (e.g., 'x' symbol to a checkmark) just by changing the classname. Let me know if you're interested in more about icoMoon; I'm a huge fan.

Comment: Sure thing, sounds interesting :) I'd like to hear more about it.

Comment: It's easy to use, and the basic pack is free. Look it up and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

Just try using  Math.random() instead of d.getTime(). It should work. Like this:

document.getElementById("validation_gif").src = "images/validation/validation_gif.gif?" + Math.random();

Comment: I already did, as stated in my OP. That does not work. All it does is give the same images on the page the same random number.

Comment: Have you used it without Math.floor() ??

Comment: Yup I tried. But, it changes nothing, as it's simply a number as well.

Comment: Try this :  document.getElementById("validation_gif").src = 
      "images/validation/validation_gif.gif?" + Math.random();

Comment: no, I tried this just now but to no avail. Imagine the checkmark that had to be dynamically generated. I have two things side by side that require the same info: name, info, email etc. So, you fill in the name, so the loading occurs and generates the checkmark, ideally the same should happen for the other place where you have to write the name, or the email etc.